# Un-grouping excel 2010 workbooks

Tags: excel

My excel 2010 is opening different workbooks under the same window. To switch between workbooks one have to press Ctrl+F6 (Instead of Ctrl+tab)

How can I switch this off so I can work with multiple workbooks open (1 in each screen) as at the moment, if I drag/minimise/resize one excel window, all workbooks do the same (hidden in a "layer" behind)

I'm using excel 2010 but the templates I'm running might be created on an older excel. Windows 7 - 64 bit

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is something that was "fixed" in 2013+ versions of Excel, but bugged me to no end in the older versions.

I've found opening a blank workbook from the taskbar (right-click > Microsoft Excel 2010) will open a new application window. Then if that window has focus, when you double-click your new file it will open in that instance rather than grouping it in the existing window.

I never discovered a better way around it.

Comment: Thanks for your solution, asking a team member, they work around by opening a new instance of excel and than file > open > "search file to be opened" instead of opening from windows explorer which would group into active window.

Comment: NP - you can also drag the new Excel file into the new instance, which personally I find easier if the right directory is there in front of you.

Comment: Disadvantage of this method is that you cannot easily copy and paste between the two instances as Excel treats the clipboard contents as if it originates from a foreign application. Personally I strongly prefer the way Excel handled workbook windows prior to Excel 2013. Where control+tab properly worked and you could arrange multiple workbooks in the same window.